# Cumulative stacked bar plot with the same variable with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I got a data frame `producers` with two colums: person_id and year.

```
    # A tibble: 3,207 x 2
   person_id      year 
   <chr>          <chr>
 1 GASH1991-04-30 2020 
 2 LOSP1969-06-29 2020 
 3 CRGM1989-08-26 2020 
 4 CEVE1954-07-15 2020 
 5 HERR1998-01-06 2020 
 6 TOLR1951-04-09 2020 
 7 BEAM1953-09-07 2020 
 8 ANRJ1977-07-06 2020 
 9 PAMH1982-02-06 2020 
10 AKTE1967-11-15 2020 
# ... with 3,197 more rows
```

I can summarise this dataframe to obtain cumulative sum:

```
  producers %>%
    select(person_id, year) %>%
    group_by(year) %>%
    distinct(person_id) %>%
    summarise(total = n()) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(cum = cumsum(total))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  year  total   cum
  <chr> <int> <int>
1 2019    456   456
2 2020   1832  2288
3 2021    160  2448
```

An I can make a cummulative bar plot like this:

```
ggplot(producers, aes(x = as.factor(year), y = as.integer(cum))) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
  ylim(0,3000) +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("Producers") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

But what I really want is something like this:

[image]

I've been trying with `aes(fill = year)` and other arguments but I can't get it. Thanks for your responses.

Comment: How do you have years on the x-axis as well year as different colours ? How would bar for 2021 have all 3 years in them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach. Ultimately, we'll need two "year" variables, one to mark the category within each stack, and one to mark which stack we want it to appear in. Here, I set up `year2` for the 2nd one, and filter out the values that shouldn't appear yet in each stack.

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  year = 2019:2021,
  total = c(456, 1832, 160)
)

library(tidyverse)
df2 %>%
  crossing(year2 = df2$year) %>%   # make copy for each year
  filter(year <= year2) %>%        # keep just the years up to current year
  ggplot(aes(year2, total, fill = fct_rev(as.factor(year)))) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Year")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ggplot2 works best with data in a long format where you have one variable to plot and then various identifying variables to control the fill, color, and facetting. Here I explicitly build a repeated data frame using `map_dfr` which essentially is running a for loop for each year in the input dataset. In `dat_long` the new column `yearid` becomes the x-axis identifier so within 2021 we can access the data for `year` 2019 through 2021 to control the color fill.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(forcats)

year = c(2019, 2020, 2021)
sum = c(456, 1832, 160)
cumsum = c(456, 2288, 2448)

dat <- data.frame(year, sum) 
# note: don't need the cumsum column
# instead, create long, replicated data where we repeat 
# each years entry for every year that comes after it
dat_long <- 
  map_dfr(unique(dat$year),
        ~filter(dat, year <= .x) %>% 
          mutate(yearid = .x)) 

ggplot(data = dat_long, 
       aes(x = yearid,
           y = sum, 
           # note: use factor to get discrete color palette, fct_rev to stack 2021 on top
           fill = fct_rev(factor(year)))) + 
  geom_col()
```